# How to use biserial to calculate correlation between continuous and categorical variable?

Tags: r, correlation, continuous, categorical-data

I am trying to calculate the correlation between `x` (continuous variable) and `y` (categorical variable) in R.

The function `biserial` in the `psych` package is used to calculate this. See [here](http://www.personality-project.org/r/psych/help/tetrachor.html).

But when I actually used it, I got a warning message and NA as the correlation:

```
Warning message:
In biserialc(x[, j], y[, i], j, i) : For x = 1 y = 1 y is not dichotomous
```

Does anyone actually use this function and get the right results?

UPDATE:

Here is the reproducible code:

```
 library(psych)
x=c(5,3,4,8,7,7,4,9,6,8,11,5,1,4,4,9,5,9,10,2,9,3,6,9,3,9,7,14,7,6,8,10,6,10,2,8,6,4,12,11,1,8,7,7,12,6,5,6,8,9)
y=c(2,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1)
 biserial(x,y)
```

The output is

```
 Biserial |                                                                                                            |   0%
       [,1]
 [1,]   NA
 Warning message:
In biserialc(x[, j], y[, i], j, i) : For x = 1 y = 1 y is not dichotomous
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the code that the error is being generated from?

Comment: It would also be helpful to include sample data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver and Alex! The code is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `y` is not dichotomous, it doesn't make sense to use `biserial()`. From the documentation:

> The biserial correlation is between a continuous y variable and a dichotmous x variable, which is assumed to have resulted from a dichotomized normal variable.

Instead use `polyserial()`, which allows more than 2 levels.

`polyserial()` requires matrices as input, so structure your command like this:

```
> polyserial(as.matrix(x), as.matrix(y))
          [,1]
[1,] 0.2672098
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! I was wrong as I didn't read the documentation clearly.  Biserial is a special case of the polyserial correlation, which is the inferred latent correlation between a continuous variable (X) and a ordered categorical variable (e.g., an item response).